# Does 20 Millegausse near outlet with nothing plugged in suggest faulty wiring?

Tags: emf

Meterk EMF meter showing 20+ millegausse near two outlets only. Both outlets have nothing plugged in. Possible live and neutral wires faulty?

Comment: The gauss, abbreviated as G or Gs, is the cgs unit of measurement of magnetic flux density (or "magnetic induction") (B). It is named after German mathematician and physicist Carl Friedrich Gauss. 0.001 G is one milligauss. The cgs system has been superseded by the International System of Units (SI), which uses the tesla (symbol T) as the unit of magnetic flux density. What is a "merterk"?

Comment: @Transistor... "meter"?

Comment: Sorry it’s the Meterk EMF meter showing 20 millegausse near the outlets and 10 milliegauss up through the wall where wiring is.

Comment: Outlets are often daisy-chained

Comment: In two separate rooms opposite sides of unit.

Comment: 20 mG at 50 or 60Hz is not even enough to raise a "bug's whisker"  of energy   and is just the stray field between the socket and about 10 orders of magnitude below the energy in a CAT scan or MRI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because there's nothing plugged into the outlets doesn't meant that there's no current flowing in the wiring - if they're part of a chain or ring there could be a draw elsewhere that causes the field.

Near the two-core wire (twin and earth, but only two carry current normally), there'll be a field that is very local, since the effect of the two opposing currents cancel out at significant distances, but near the socket where the conductors are separated more, there will be a stronger field.

Answer (score 3):

> Meterk EMF meter

I assume you mean [this meter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0754VVW4W), or one very much like it?

This type of meter is effectively a toy made for pseudoscientific purposes like "[ghost hunting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_hunting)" and investigating "[electrosensitivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_hypersensitivity)". It is not a reliable nor an accurate instrument for measuring electrical or magnetic fields.